# Lambda iteratorAge metric does not show percentiles

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, metrics

Lambda iterationAge metric does not show any data for percentiles in any time period besides "average", "max", "min" and "sample count". Lambda has been running for over a month already. Does iteratorAge metric in Lambda supports P95, P99? I cant seem to find it on the official docs.

Answer (score 0):

We see this as well. If you look at [this page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/monitoring-metrics.html#monitoring-metrics-types), under 'Performance metrics', it states:

> Duration also supports percentile (p) statistics. Use percentiles to exclude outlier values that skew Average and Maximum statistics. For example, the p95 statistic shows the maximum duration of 95 percent of invocations, excluding the slowest 5 percent. For more information, see Percentiles in the Amazon CloudWatch User Guide.

But we do have some graphs from incidents that have p95 for Lambda Iterator age. My suspicion is that it only gets recorded if it's non-zero, but I've not been able to confirm.